# I have Win10 running in a VBox (5.2.32) on my kubuntu (18.04) host. It can no longer communicate with my USB scanner.o USB devices attached

Tags: usb, virtualbox, kubuntu, scanner

I have a Win10 guest in a VBox (5.2.32) on my kubuntu (18.04) host. It can not communicate with my USB scanner. I have installed the ext-pack and the guest-additions but Win10 still thinks there are no USB devices attached. I am using a USB mouse which Win10 can handle, but it can't detect my USB external drive or my USB scanner.  WHat is confusing is that I had the same setup on an earlier computer (PowerSpec G313) which worked perfectly. I upgraded to a newer model (PowerSpec B742) which I set up the same way and now have that USB problem.
I have spent an embarrassing amount of time trying to overcome this obstacle and am now in need of some advice.

Comment: I have enabled USB in the VM Virtualbox Manager and set up USB filters for my Epson scanner and my Toshiba 2Tb external drive (as I had on my previous computer). I also (re)installed the Guest-Additions in my Win10 guest. But those two USB devices are still invisible to my guest.

Answer (score 0):

After doing all of the things in my question, my comment, and also adding my primary user ID to vboxusers, I finally rebooted my host. After that reboot my guest was able to access my scanner.